# How to use command line arguments to change variables

Tags: python

I'm developing a game in pygame and I'm trying to use command line arguments.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do with a description at the top:

```
# user sets variables with command lines. some options:
# python test.py (all default settings)
# python test.py -f (for fog)
# python test.py -f -m (for fog and multiplayer)
# python test.py -m (for multiplayer)

# default settings
fog = False
mode = 'singleplayer'

if fog == True:
    print(1)
else:
    print(2)
    
if mode == 'multiplayer':
    print(3)
```

How do I make it so that the user can type an option as stated in my 4 test cases and it will change the value of my variables?

I've looked at https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse and wasn't able to understand how I can do what I want to do.

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is only for questions about [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news), but not for questions about games written in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example in the [argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). You would do something like:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-m', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.f)
print(args.m)
```